# View moves back and forth when swiping in listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view with each list item containing a button (with a text on it) and an image. I am trying to implement swiping a swiping effect when the user touches the listitem and moves his finger to the left or right. This is my code in **`onIntercetTouchEvent`**

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mDownX=motionEvent.getX();
                Log.i(TAG, "onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float deltaX=motionEvent.getX()-mDownX;
                int mSwipingSlop=deltaX>0?mSlop:-mSlop;
                this.setTranslationX(deltaX-mSwipingSlop);
                Log.i(TAG, "onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE");
                break;
```

It works. But the problem is that there is a blurring effect when the swiping is happening. Even though I am swiping in one direction, **button in the view seems to move back and forth very fast and thus giving a blurring effect**. 
Can anyone tell what is the problem here and a possible solution?

**Printing value of deltaX in for ACTION_MOVE**
﹕

```
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN
\ onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---13.481277
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---4.9546204
\onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---16.477112
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---30.629227
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---33.33777
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---53.111282
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---53.15001
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---74.20006
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---75.70354
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---94.25169
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---95.33977
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---116.58623
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---117.084274
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---140.37877
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---137.01903
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---157.82243
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---152.6262
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---172.87059
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---165.39714
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---182.45793
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---174.23326
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---190.94212
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---182.86662
onInterceptTouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE---196.75847
```

Comment: What if you just execute `this.setTranslationX(deltaX)`?

Comment: @NiekHaarman : The blurring effect is less/not significant initially in that case. But after the first swipe if you again try to swipe you can again see the same blurring effect. NOTE that I am not dismissing the view after swiping. I want to continue swiping the view from where I left it last

Comment: Can you print out the translationX you're setting in the move events? Are they monotone increasing / decreasing?

Comment: @NiekHaarman : Done. They don't seem to be monotonously increasing. There is some discrepancy. It is not a constant increase or decrease. But the swipe is constant increasing. I mean I am swiping only in one direction

Comment: It seems that you receive events twice: every second value seems correct. Does this same behavior occur if you use `onTouchEvent`? You may need to return `true` in  `onInterceptTouchEvent` if your child views would steal them.

Comment: @NiekHaarman : I had tried OnTouchEvent. But the problem with that was that the button and the immageview in the listitem was consuming the touch. And only when clicking the border of the list item and dragging  was I able to see the swipe action. But I tried printing the log for that. Yes it is constantly increasing unlike for OnInterceptEvent

Comment: So when removing your button, the swipe works as expected? If so, I think I can come up with the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59223/discussion-between-ashwin-and-niek-haarman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the problem, and this seems to work: instead of `setTranslationX(deltaX-mSwipingSlop)`, use `setX(getX() + deltaX-mSwipingSlop)`.

Using `getRawX()` instead of `getX()` works as well, but needs some extra calculations to accommodate for second gestures.

I am not entirely sure why this behavior occurs though.