# Why is my FrameLayout so choppy when I move it with my finger?

Tags: android

I'm doing some tests on moving a FrameLayout with my finger using an onTouchListener(). One issue I'm seeing is that the FrameLayout does not truely follow my finger movements, the other issue is that the FrameLayout is extremely choppy when I move it. By choppy I mean the FrameLayout bounces between two locations on the screen extremely fast when I move it with my finger. I have tried this with an ImageView instead of a FrameLayout and have gotten the same choppiness. What am I doing wrong?

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#808080" 
    android:id="@+id/parent_frame">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" 
        android:id="@+id/child_frame">
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private FrameLayout parent_frame;
private FrameLayout child_frame;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    parent_frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_frame);
    child_frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.child_frame);

    child_frame.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        float x;
        float y;
        float last_x;
        float last_y;
        float dx;
        float dy;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();
                last_x = x;
                last_y = y;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();
                dx = x - last_x;
                dy = y - last_y;
                child_frame.setTranslationX(child_frame.getTranslationX() + dx);
                child_frame.setTranslationY(child_frame.getTranslationY() + dy);
                last_x = x;
                last_y = y;
                break;
            }


            return true;
        }
    });

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271128/view-moves-back-and-forth-when-swiping-in-listview-in-android/25273830#25273830) a while back.

The solution was to use `setX(getX() + ...)` instead of `setTranslationX(...)`. I still don't know why this behavior occurs though.

Comment: I get a better response with this method but still get a dual FrameLayouts when I move it with my finger.